# Accessing $refs array inside a Vue JS Instance watch object

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am building a **Vue JS** SPA, and have a **Vuetify data-table** inside of the v-app. I am trying to set a variable inside the **watch object** for the **filteredItems computed property** inside the data-table but I am unsure of how to access the **$refs array** inside the instance.

I know that the data is accessible within the instance by using:

```
this.$refs['prospectsTable'].filteredItems
```

However the same reference name does not work within the watch object. I have tried:

```
$refs['prospectsTable'].filteredItems: function(newItems) {
            console.log(newItems);
        }

&

this.$refs['prospectsTable'].filteredItems: function(newItems) {
            console.log(newItems);
        }
```

**How can i access the $refs array inside of the watch function?**

```
var p = new Vue({
    el: '#prospectsApp',
    data: () => ({}), 

    watch: function() {
        // How can i access the $refs array inside of the watch function?
        $refs['prospectsTable'].filteredItems: function() {

        }
    }
});




<div id="prospectsApp">
    <v-app id="inspire" v-cloak>
        <v-data-table ref="prospectsTable" v-model="selected" :headers="headers" :items="prospects" :pagination.sync="pagination" select-all item-key="id" class="elevation-1" > 
            <template v-slot:headers="props">
                <tr>
                    <th><v-checkbox :input-value="props.all" color="#c79121" :indeterminate="props.indeterminate" primary hide-details @click.stop="toggleAllSelected"></v-checkbox></th>
                    <th v-for="header in props.headers" :key="header.text"
                        :class="['column sortable', pagination.descending ? 'desc' : 'asc', header.value === pagination.sortBy ? 'active' : '']"
                        @click="changeSort(header.value)">
                        <v-icon small>arrow_upward</v-icon>
                        @{{ header.text }}
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </template>

            <template v-slot:items="props">
                <tr :active="props.selected" @click="props.selected = !props.selected">
                    <td class="text-center align-middle">
                        <v-checkbox :input-value="props.selected" primary hide-details color="#c79121"></v-checkbox>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center align-middle">@{{ props.item.id }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <div>@{{ props.item.name }}</div>
                        <div v-show="props.item.contacted" class="label label-success"><span class="fa fa-check-square-o"></span> Contacted!</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>@{{ props.item.foodcat.title }}</td>
                    <td>@{{ props.item.contact_fname }}<span v-if="props.item.contact_lname"> @{{ props.item.contact_lname }}</span><span v-if="props.item.contact_title">, @{{ props.item.contact_title }}</span></td>
                    <td>@{{ props.item.response_notes }}</td>
                    <td class="text-right align-middle">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" @click="updateContacted(props.item.id)" v-show="!props.item.contacted"><span class="fa fa-check-square-o"></span> Mark As Contacted</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" @click="editProspect(props.item.id)"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span> Edit Lead</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" @click="removeProspect(props.item.id)"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span> Delete Lead</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </template>
            <template slot="no-data">
                <p class="text-xs-center">No Data</p>
            </template>                                
        </v-data-table>
    </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try `import Vue from "vue";` and then using the global `Vue.$refs` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be sat in $root because of where the component it is declared.

If `$refs.prospectsTable` is not working then try `$root.$refs.prospectsTable`.

Perhaps also this should be keys in a watcher as a string like so:

```
watch: {

   '$refs.prospectsTable.filteredItems': function (value) {
       console.log(value);
   }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to add watcher on the mounted. Try the following code.

```
mounted(){
       this.$watch(
        () => {
            return this.$refs.prospectsTable.filteredItems
        },
      (val) => {
        console.log(val)
        alert('App $watch $refs.counter.i: ' + val)
      }
    )
  }
```

Codepen - https://codesandbox.io/s/j7wjjypnxw

Comment: Thank you. It's was helped me. Like