# How to retrieve the filtered data table items (as an array) when using a custom data table search filter

Tags: search, datatable, vuetify.js

There is nice documentation of vuetify version 2 about how override the default data table search filtering used with search prop by supplying a function to the custom-filter prop [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#custom-filtering).

Everything understood / it works fine.

But how can I **retrieve the filtered data table items** (as an array) within the custom search filter method in vuetify version 2?

```
methods: {
      filterOnlyCapsText (value, search, item) {
        ...
        //want to do sth like this here
        this.filteredTableData = items;
        ...

      },
```

Here is the complete [pen from the vuetify documentation example](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101).

Comment: I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55387933/accessing-refs-array-inside-a-vue-js-instance-watch-object), but doesn't seem to be valid anymore it suggests ```watch: {
   '$refs.someTableRefName.filteredItems': function (value) {
       console.log(value);
   }
}``` as how to retrieve the filtered data table items

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution?