# Vue js watch vue pretty checkbox values

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, event-handling

I am using vue pretty checkbox to display a checkbox. However, based on if one of the checkboxes is checked or not my content has to change! So, I need something like a listener on those vue pretty checkbox components.

However, because vue pretty checkbox is a package I cannot modify the code. My question now is, how can I listen on those checkboxes if they have changed from another component.

Because the `products-manager` component gets the values. So, whenever the values of the checkboxes of the `p-check` inside the `product-filter` changes, I need to pass that to the `products-manager` component in order to reload the data!

Any ideas on how I can do this? I have already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51225378/how-to-watch-child-properties-changes-from-parent-component) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55387933/accessing-refs-array-inside-a-vue-js-instance-watch-object) but those aren't working for me...

Very important: The number of checkboxes is dynamically as you can see below. The first two checkboxes are always there but the checkbox below gets genereated by a `v-for`!

This is my sourcecode so far (home template):

```
<div id="home" class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-12" id="product-sort-and-filter">
        <products-filter ref="productsFilter" :product-types-prop="{{ json_encode($productTypes) }}"></products-filter>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-9">
        <div class="products">
            <products-manager ref="productsManager" :products-prop="{{ json_encode($products) }}" auth="{{ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::check() }}" :userprop="{{ json_encode(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()) }}" route="{{ route('product.index') }}"></products-manager>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-3">
        <sidebar-manager ref="SidebarManager" :top-products-today-prop="{{ json_encode($products) }}" :top-products-week-prop="{{ json_encode($products) }}" :top-products-month-prop="{{ json_encode($products) }}"></sidebar-manager>
    </div>
</div>
```

products filter component:

```
<template>
    <div class="product-sort-and-filter-wrapper d-flex">
        <div class="col-xl-9 product-sorting no-padding">
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li class="list-inline-item">Highlights</li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">Aktuell</li>
                <li class="list-inline-item">Diskutiert</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xl-3 product-filter no-padding text-right">
            <div class="dropdown d-inline-flex">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fas fa-filter"></i>FILTERN</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" style="margin-top: 0px">
                    <div class="productTypesBoxes dropdown-item pretty-checkbox-wrapper">
                        <p-check name="productExpiredCheckbox" class="p-svg p-plain p-bigger p-smooth" ref="showExpired" toggle true-value false-value>
                            <span class="checkbox-label on rubik-medium">Abgelaufene anzeigen</span>
                            <label slot="off-label"><span class="checkbox-label off rubik-medium">Abgelaufene anzeigen</span></label>
                            <span slot="extra" class="svg"><i data-feather="check-square"></i></span>
                            <span slot="off-extra" class="svg"><i data-feather="square"></i></span>
                        </p-check>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <div class="productTypesBoxes dropdown-item pretty-checkbox-wrapper">
                        <p-check name="productTypeCheckbox" class="p-svg p-plain p-bigger p-smooth" ref="showAllProductTypes" toggle true-value false-value checked>
                            <span class="checkbox-label on rubik-medium">Alle anzeigen</span>
                            <label slot="off-label"><span class="checkbox-label off rubik-medium">Alle anzeigen</span></label>
                            <span slot="extra" class="svg"><i data-feather="check-square"></i></span>
                            <span slot="off-extra" class="svg"><i data-feather="square"></i></span>
                        </p-check>
                    </div>
                    <div class="productTypesBoxes sub dropdown-item pretty-checkbox-wrapper" v-for="productType in productTypes">
                        <p-check name="productTypeCheckbox" :value="productType.id" class="p-svg p-plain p-bigger p-smooth" :ref="'productType' + productType.id" toggle>
                            <span class="checkbox-label on ">{{ productType.label }}</span>
                            <label slot="off-label"><span class="checkbox-label off ">{{ productType.label }}</span></label>
                            <span slot="extra" class="svg"><i data-feather="check-square"></i></span>
                            <span slot="off-extra" class="svg"><i data-feather="square"></i></span>
                        </p-check>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "ProductsFilter",
        props: ['productTypesProp'],
        data() {
            return {
                highlights: true,
                aktuell: false,
                diskutiert: false,
                showExipredDeals: false,
                productTypes: this.productTypesProp
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: Whenever you need to listen to the state of a third-party component, you'll need to rely on events that the component emits, in this case, probably `onChange`. Maybe [this issue from the pretty-checkbox-vue repo](https://github.com/hamed-ehtesham/pretty-checkbox-vue/issues/20) can help? (The [API docs](https://github.com/hamed-ehtesham/pretty-checkbox-vue#usage) on it don't have anything on the events emitted by this component, which is poor documentation imo).

Comment: Yes... in my opinion too... But thanks for the link. However, this is not very helpful... Do you know how to use it or can you give me an example?

Comment: I have figured it out! Thank you anyway! :)

Comment: Do you have an idea how to figure out which `<p-check>` has been updated? This is very important for me!

Comment: Can you pass something to your change handler function to identify it? Eg. `@change="myFunc($event, productType.id)"`

Comment: Yes, thank you a lot!!! Now I get the `productType.id` back as well! Just one last question: If all `productType.id` checkboxes have been selected I want to set the `All` checkboxes to true and the other way around. Do you maybe know how to do this? I think I have to do this with `refs` or?

Comment: Sweet! If you use `v-model` with the "all" checkbox, you'd be able set the value of the property it's attached to and the checkbox would update accordingly. I *think* you'd be able to use the `checked` prop on it to change its value as well, if you need a more manual approach.

Comment: Also for reference, `refs` should *generally* be avoided unless specifically referenced by a component's API. Since a ref reaches inside the implementation of a component, it can be easily broken by future changes if not intentionally preserved by the developer. The Vue docs recommend them as a kind of "escape hatch," for edge use cases only.

Comment: Yeah, thats clear so far. But I need to change the `checked` value for all the other `<p-check>` checkboxes to true and thats something I cannot do via `v-model`, or can I? Also, the `@change="myFunc($event, productType.id)"` is now telling my `product-filter` component that the `<p-check>` value has changed. But how can I tell this now my `product-manager` which is not the parent or child of `product-filter` (take a look at my `home.blade.php` file above)

Comment: You can definitely use `v-model` for that if you want to, but you'll need to investigate the best syntax for doing that for checkboxes in a `v-for`. As for telling `product-manager` about changes in `product-filter`, you can do that in a few ways. 2 of them: you could use a state management solution, like Vuex, or you could emit an event to the parent of `product-filter` and then pass an updated prop to `product-manager` in reaction to that event, which follows the Vue philosophy of "props down, events up." Best of luck to figuring the rest of this out! :)